# how to create saperate database tables for each new site/client registration in wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress

how to create separate database tables for each new site/client registration in WordPress multi site with their username.And also saperate media folder for saperate site as for ex. in multisite the structure is /wp-content/uploads/sites/ID Number of site>Date but i need autogenerate folder in client and upload like autogenerated folder/uploads/date .

Comment: sorry can't understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40678589/edit) your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. [You should also read How to Ask.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)